# Java - socket connects only sometimes Android

Tags: java, android, sockets

This is driving me crazy. I know it  is not allowed to create socket connection in UI Thread, so I create a separate thread first and try to connect to a local server. In 3 out of 5 debugs on my Acer Iconia tab A500 i can't see a single packet outgoing from the device to local server. (w/ wireshark)

Why is this happening? Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Thread t= new Thread(){
public void run(){

Socket sck;

try {   

sck = new Socket("192.168.1.96", 7777); 

} catch (Exception e) {

}

}
};

    t.start();
}


}
```

Comment: Where do you start the thread & what's the exception in the catch block?

Comment: sorry forgot that bit, edited my post.

Comment: There is no exception. It just won't send any SYN packet.

Comment: Have you enabled internet permission in manifest?

Comment: Yes, how else would it connect in other two tries.

Comment: Don't use an empty `catch(Exception)`! If the socket creation encounters a problem you won't know about it. At least log the error using `Log.e("socket","exception", e)` or something.

Comment: this is just an example of what I do. There is no exception at all when I debug it.